# Variable naming conventions in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions, oop

In PHP, we (at least the good programmers) always start general variable names with a lower-case letter, but class variables/objects with an upper-case letter to distinguish them. In the same way we start general file names with a lower case letter, but files containing Classes with an upper case letter.

E.g.:

```php
<?php
    $number = 123;
    $string = "a string";
    $colors_array = array('red', 'blue', 'red');
    $Cat = New Cat();
?>
```

Are the conventions the same in Java, i.e., objects starting with upper-case, but the rest with lower case, or does everything start with lower case as I've read in other places?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Generally, all variables will start with lower case:

```
int count = 32;
double conversionFactor = 1.5d;
```

Some people like to put static constants in all case:

```
public static final double KILOGRAM_TO_POUND = 2.20462262;
```

Things get more annoying when you deal with acronyms, and there is no real standard on whether you should use:

```
HTMLHandler myHtmlHandler;
```

or

```
HTMLHandler myHTMLHandler.
```

Now, either way, note that the class names (Object, String, HTMLHandler) always start with a capital letter, but individual object variables start lowercase.

Comment: I prefer myHtmlHandler because you dont have to worry about wether a term is considered an acronym or word (LASER, AJAX, GUID).

Comment: Actually, the JDK's convention is to use all-caps for acronyms. For example: userID, URI, UUID, SQLException. This was a decision made around JDK 1.3-1.4 IIRC, so that's why you'll see a mix of conventions in the JDK itself. Also, confusingly, some of the JSRs, like JAX-RS, ended up using different conventions for whatever reason, but other major standards like Swing and Java EE use the all-caps convention.

Comment: I also think if an acronym is well known enough to be used in the first place then it's not harmful to make it lower case: getTcpHeader() rather than getTCPHeader().  Not to mention it is basically incompatible with camel case / mixed case.

Comment: If we write it as 'HTML' then it breaks the fundamental principle of camelCase that the capital letters denote new words.  Plus it's difficult to know what to do when the acronym comes at the beginning of the word.  The fact that the class is called 'HTMLHandler' is irrelevant, since the name of a variable should not be related to its type ('myHtmlHandler' is a bad name, for example)

Answer (score 64):

You can find the naming in the [Java Code Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html#367).

A quick summary:

- For classes, use [upper camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).
- For class members and local variables use [lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)
- For packages, use reverse URIs, e.g., *org.acme.project.subsystem*
- For constants, use [uppercase](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uppercase#Adjective).

Comment: On the *"Java Code Conventions"* page: *"The information on this page is for archive purposes only. This page is not being actively maintained. Links within the documentation may not work and the information itself may no longer be valid. The last revision to this document was made on April 20, 1999"*

Answer (score 9):

- variablesAndMethodsLikeThis
- ClassesLikeThis
- CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS

Answer (score 4):

The convention is that class names start with an uppercase letter. Variable names are [lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). Even if the variable references an object, it still starts with lower case.

[This page](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html) should help.

Answer (score 0):

The conventions really depend on the individual place you're coding for.

In general, from what I've seen classes are [upper camel cased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (with upper case first), methods start with lower case, and variables I've seen all over the place (some upper camel cased, some [lower camel cased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) with first letter lower (as mentioned in previous answers, this is the norm), some even with [Hungarian notation](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/)).  It depends on your style and the style that the project you're working on has adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Some people (who are not me) like to differentiate *method* variables from [*instance* variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) by prefixing *instance* variables with "this."  This also fixes the problem that occurs when assigning a parameter to an *instance* variable of the same name:

```
public ConstructorMethod(MyVar variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
}
```

But then some people feel you should always use that pattern—but I'm not crazy about it—I think it's overkill if you keep your methods and classes small.

Also, some people use a naming pattern for parameters. This (again) comes in handy when you are assigning from a constructor to an *instance* variable:

```
public ConstructorMethod(MyVar pVariable) {
    variable = pVariable;
}
```

Usually the pattern is `pVariable` or `_variable`. I occasionally use this because I find it more readable than this, but it has the disadvantage of making your Javadocs less readable.

In any case, I don't really like the idea of *always* using any of these patterns. They are great to know, but if you really need help differentiating them throughout your code, tell [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to show them in different colors.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using [lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for instance methods and [upper camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (Pascal case) for static?

I think it could be very helpful, because there wouldn't be any issues while verifying which method is static. It's my proposal.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. Would it be bad if I did that in my code, since it's not an accepted standard right now?