# conflict b/w string and string[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables

Basically I have a class that has methods which use String arrays and i'm writing a method in the application  class to read a file and update an array of object of class Customer. I get errors like:

Line 83: set_address(java.lang.String[]) in Customer cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
at the line review[i].set_address(st[1]). I understand that it is looking for a string[] and it is receiving a string but is there any way to fix this? Here's the code I'm working with.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Customer {

int account_id;
char[] ch1 = new char[20];
String name = new String (ch1);
char[] ch2 = new char[80];
String address = new String (ch2);
char[] ch3 = new char[10];
String phone_number = new String (ch3);
char[] ch4 = new char[8];
String date_of_birth = new String (ch4);
double account_balance;

public int get_accountid(){
       return account_id;
}

public String get_address(){
       return address;
}

public String get_phone_number(){
       return phone_number;
}

public String get_date_of_birth(){
       return date_of_birth;
}

public double get_balance(){
       return account_balance;
}

public void set_account_id(int num){
       account_id = num;
}

public void set_address(String add){
       address = add;
}

public void set_phone_number(String phone){
       phone_number = phone;
}

public void set_date_of_birth(String dob){
       date_of_birth = dob;
}

public void set_balance(double bal){
       account_balance = bal;
}
Customer(){ // default constructor
}

// parametrized constructor
Customer(int id, String name, String add, String dob, String num, double bal){
    this.account_id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = add;
    this.date_of_birth = dob;
    this.phone_number = num;
    this.account_balance = bal;
}

}


     public class lab2{
     public static void main(String args[]){

     System.out.println("testing this shit");    
      }
      public static void readFile(String filename){
          Customer[] review = new Customer[30];
          int i=0; 
          Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File (filename));
          while (scan.hasNext()){

               while(i<30){

                      review[i].set_account_id(scan.nextInt());
                  String[] st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                  review[i].set_address(st[1]);
                  st = scan.nextLine().spilt("=");
                      review[i].set_phone_number(st[1]);
                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      review[i].set_date_of_birth(st[1]);
                      //st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      review[i].set_balance(scan.nextDouble());
                      scan.nextLine();
                      i=i+1;
             }
        }
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `Customer` looks like a Java bean. I find these declaration suspicious:

```
String[] name = new String [20];
String[] address = new String [80];
String[] phone_number = new String [10];
String[] date_of_birth = new String [8];
```

Why do you want a `Customer` to have 20 names, 80 addresses, 10 phone numbers, and 8 date of birth? I suspect that your intention is saying that a `Customer` name is at most 20 characters long, his/her address is at most 80 characters long, etc. If this is the case, than you don't want a `String[]`, you may want a char[]!

However, think about making those fields simply `String`: it seems more natural. I don't see reason why you may want to limit their size.

Comment: yeah that would be true. the input file has 30 records of customers which i take care of in the readFIle method. i wasn't sure on how to use the split method with char[] though?

Comment: @dawnoflife: `split` returns a `String[]`: you must know which `String` in this array is the one you want to assign as a value of a `Customer` field. I see that you split on `=`, so I presume you have lines like `phone=55512344` where `55512344` is the value for the field `phone_number` of your `Customer` instance, so you could do `st = scan.nextLine().spilt("="); review[i].set_phone_number(st[1]);` that is taking the `String` at position 1 of the array returned by `split`

Comment: i edited the code and incorporated char arrays. now i just a random split error on line 88 with st = scan.nextLine().split("=").it doesn't give any errors int the subsequent calls of split.

Comment: @dawnoflife: also consider using a more java-oriented naming conventions for your variables. See [Variable naming conventions in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java) :)

Comment: @dawnoflife: I think you'd better use `String` rather than `char[]`: see my comment above

Comment: i still use the variables of type string. I just used char arrays to intialize strings...or is that wrong?

Comment: @dawnoflife: if your variables are of type `String`, then initialize them by passing a `String`. `split` gives you a `String[]` (i.e. an array of `String`s): you just have to pick the right one for initializing your variable. Again, see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your method signature:

```
public void set_address(String add){
       address = add;
}
```

Or other choice: You create a new String[] object based on your String object an pass this:

Comment: this would mean i would have to change the datatypes of the variables declared initially too right?

Comment: @dawnoflife for the first alternative yes, for the second no

Comment: how do i declare new strings then?

Comment: String address = ""; or String address; or String address = new String();

Comment: i need them to be of specific sizes?

Comment: Only arrays have specific sizes.

Comment: alright then how do i incorporate the code with string arrays?