# How can I compare String value with ArrayList of String type in Java?

Tags: java

My requirement is comparing `String` to `ArrayList` which contains a list of strings. Can any one suggest me?

Comment: What exactly do you want? You can't compare a `String` to an `ArrayList`. Be precise and show what you did until now.

Comment: What do you mean "compare"? Do you mean check if the ArrayList contains a particular String?

Comment: ya i want to check one sting whether it is present in ArrayList or not? in java

Answer (score 22):

Use

```
ArrayList.contains("StringToBeChecked");
```

If the String is present in the ArrayList, this function will return true, else will return false.

Comment: just curious about capital A - the first letter in `ArrayList.contains("StringToBeChecked");`

Comment: I didn't give the exact name of the variable. Gave more of an idea of what can be done. In actual scenario, instead of `ArrayList`, use your variable of type ArrayList.

Comment: there is a [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java/414029#414029) between `ArrayList` and `arrayList` isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

Look at the [List#contains(T obj)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method, like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("xyz");
list.contains("abc"); // true
list.contains("foo"); // false
```

Comment: Arrays.asList("abc","xyz").contains("abc");

Answer (score 8):

This is your method:

```
   private boolean containsString(String testString, ArrayList<String> list) 
   {
        return list.contains(testString);
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are different options you could consider :

- a simple for each loop using equals on each member of your list to compare it to string A.
- sorting all strings in list in order to boost up comparison and find if a string in the list matches A.
- using a sortedSet to achieve the above
- putting alls string in the intern string pool using intern method on every item in the list and on string A. This will allow to compare strings using == and not equal anymore. Comparison would then be much faster.
- using a hashmap to achieve better comparison speeds
- an identity hashmap to mix the two preceding strategies.

Well, the are pros and cons to those methods, it all depends on what you want to do and why and how you compare strings.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 4):

ArrayList can contain one or more Strings. You cannot compare String with ArrayList. But you can check whether the ArrayList contains that String ot not using `contains()` method

```
String str = //the string which you want to compare
ArrayList myArray =// my array list
boolean isStringExists = myArray.contains(str);// returns true if the array list contains string value as specified by user
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use [Lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/), then check the presence of the String as:

```
private boolean isContains(ArrayList<String> listOfStrings, String testString) {
    return (Lambda.select(listOfStrings, Matchers.equalTo(testString)).size() != 0);  
}
```

Using static import of `select` and `equalTo` increase the readability:

```
select(listOfStrings, equalTo(testString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Array to Array list first

```
List al = Arrays.asList("Your Array");
```

Then compare using contains or equals

```
if (al.contains("Your String") {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation