# How to compare two string values from an ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, string, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that is populated with strings from a text file, and now I want to sort it alphabetically (I can't use collections.sort or anything like that, it has to be manual).

What is the correct way to compare two elements of an ArrayList (if there is one at all)?

Comment: Do you know how to compare two strings? Do you know how to retrieve two items from an array list? If you know both of those, put them together.

Comment: Care to mention why you can't use `Collections.sort` for your needs? And FWIW, `String`s are `Comparable`, so `compareTo` should do for basic lexicographic comparison.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607888/how-can-i-compare-string-value-with-arraylist-of-string-type-in-java.

Comment: It's for an assignment and we're not allowed to use Java Collections for it. And to answer the previous question, yes I do know how to do both of those things, but it's not accepting compareTo.

Comment: What do you mean by "not accepting" `compareTo`? Have you read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) of the `compareTo` to understand how it works?

Comment: I have, and I do, but when I try to apply it to ArrayList like this:

if(borrowerList.add(j).compareTo(borrowerList.add(k)) < 0)

it says it can't be applied to the primitive type Boolean.

Comment: You'll want to read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) of `Collection#add`. It returns a `boolean`, not the added string itself.

Comment: I sorted it by saving as an arraylist then reading into an array and then sorting that. :)