# setPositiveButton in AlertDialog, using strings?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to add a string to the following alert box's positive button, but it keeps spamming out error messages.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.checkNetwork).setTitle(
        R.string.checkNetworkTitle);
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning);
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.continue, new warningContinue());
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Any help? It does seem to work for the title and the message, however not for the button...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The error says:

> The method setPositiveButton(int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) in
>   the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Class, warningContinue)

So it seems to expect an integer, but I was wondering if there's any way to use strings for localization-purposes?

EDIT2:

Ok what the hell. Problem lied in the string name; it won't let me name my string continue for some reason. o_O

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the error you get?

Comment: what does "not for the button" mean?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use "android.R.string.continue". "package name".R.string.continue is what you want. Thats the usual way you're doing localization in android. The id provides multilanguage support automatically based on the users system language. You just have to create multiple "values" directories. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html provides you more information about localization.

Also you can't use "continue" as a name, use "str_continue" or something like that (it's the same for "return" or "break" ect.). They are reserved in java. For more information you could read the link: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/reservedwords.htm

Because you don't post the code of "warningContinue()", i think you know that it has to extend "DialogInterface.OnClickListener()". Also you should consider to write your classes first character uppercase for convention reasons, for more information read this answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/414029/2238341

Comment: Correct, there's no system String named android.R.string.continue. There is however a bunch of other predefined strings that you can use: android.R.string.cut, android.R.string.ok, android.R.string.cancel etc)

Answer (score 1):

`R.string.warningButton` is just the int in your R.java file. To get the associated string use the following line:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.warningButton), new warningContinue() );
```

As other mentioned, don't use android.R.string.continue as it doesn't exist in system.

Comment: Thanks man. Worked with the following though:builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.warningButton, new warningContinue() );

Comment: You're right, the solution I provided you is for the more general case: `builder.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.warningButton), new warningContinue() );`

Comment: There's two methods for defining button texts. One takes a CharSequence/String and the other takes a resource id to a String:
 
setPositiveButton(int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) and

setPositiveButton(CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)

Answer (score 0):

try, first go to res / values / strings.xml and declare your string as follows

```
<string name="checkNetwork">your String...</string>
```

Then you can take it as follows

```
R.string.checkNetwork
```

Just like this one and be happy ....