# Java object returning zeros for calculated variables

Tags: java, oop

this is my first question here and I'm very new to programming so please bear with me.

I'm taking a java class, and in my current assignment I have to create three instances of a circle, compute their diameters and areas, and print the values. The first two instances are supposed to have the radius set by a setRadius method, while the third is supposed to retain the default calculations based on a radius of 1.

edit: The problem is this: the first two objects, on which I used the setRadius method, returned correct values, but the third was intended to return default values of the constructor, and instead it returned all zeros.

Here is the code, thanks in advance!

```
//this class implements the Circle class
public class TestCircle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Circle Circle1 = new Circle();
        Circle Circle2 = new Circle();
        Circle Circle3 = new Circle();

        Circle1.setRadius(2);
        Circle2.setRadius(10);

        Circle1.display();
        Circle2.display();
        Circle3.display();
    }
}


import java.lang.Math.*;
public class Circle
{
double radius;
double diameter;
double area;

    public void Circle()
    {
        radius = 1;
        diameter = radius * 2;
        area = (radius * radius) * Math.PI;
    }

    public void setRadius(double rad)
    {
        this.radius = rad;
        diameter = radius * 2;
        area = (radius * radius) * Math.PI;
    }


    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);
        System.out.println("Diameter: " + diameter);
        System.out.println("Area: " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't say what the problem is, but your title implies that you get zeros for all three values.  Is this correct?

Comment: An important thing to do here when posing a question is to *completely* and *precisely* state the symptoms (and *explicitly* ask why those symptoms are seen).  The purpose of this site is *not* to serve as a "code review" service.

Comment: I apologize. I totally left off the part where I meant to state the issue. The issue was that the third instance of the object, which was supposed to retain the default values from the constructor, doesn't return anything. The other two instances in which the radius is set using setRadius, display the correct values.

Comment: In a more complex case that would have been a critical piece of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
public void Circle()
```

is just a method with a `void` return type. For a constructor, you need

```
public Circle() // notice there is no return type
```

Because you didn't actually provide a constructor, the following

```
Circle Circle1 = new Circle();
Circle Circle2 = new Circle();
Circle Circle3 = new Circle();
```

used a default constructor provided by the compiler. It has an empty body and thus the field values are all initialized to `0` by default.

And since you only call `setRadius()` on two of them, the other one will only show values of `0`.

Read up on constructors [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

---

Java naming conventions state that variable names should start with lowercase letters and follow a `camelCase` format. You can do some further reading on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java).

Comment: Of course, that would imply that the first two cases would have returned correct values (since setRadius was called) but the third would have returned 0s (no call to setRadius).

Comment: +1 It's also worth telling the OP to follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: @arshajii - He did, mostly.  The Circle method was a coding error, not a failure to follow convention.

Comment: @HotLicks I think arshajii means for variable names.

Comment: Which variables did not meet Java conventions? radius, diameter, area, and rad are the only variable names present, and they are each just one word and hence all lower-case.

Comment: @HotLicks `Circle Circle1`.

Comment: OK, I'll grant you those.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I appreciate your help. I definitely need to read up more on constructors to get the concepts solidified in my noggin.

Comment: @user2782275 - The notation for constructors is a little flaky and non-intuitive.  It seems "normal" to folks coming from other languages, and has some "logic" behind it, but it's tricky to the novice.  And it's very easy to accidentally code something like what you did, even if you're an experienced coder.

Comment: I'm learning there is a lot of tricky, non-intuitive things about Java. My only prior programming experience is python at the novice level, and  compared to that, Java has been a handful to learn so far. Granted, I'm only two weeks along. I hope it gets better from here.