# Printing out specific data and calculations when multiple records in a CSV file

Tags: java, file, csv

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class CSVReader {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    CSVReader obj = new CSVReader();
    obj.run();
 }

 public void run() {
  String CSVFile = "/Users/Wyatt/CSVFile2.csv";
  BufferedReader br = null;
  String Line = "";
  String analysisStr;
  String CSVDelimiter = ",";
  int analysis;
  double AVGDate = 0;

  BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSVFile));
      while ((Line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] Weather = Line.split(CSVDelimiter);
          System.out.println("Weather [Date: " 
                      + Double.parseDouble(Weather[0]) + ", Interval: " 
                      + Double.parseDouble(Weather[1]) + ", Rainfall: " 
                      + Double.parseDouble(Weather[2]) + ", Sunlight: " 
                      + Double.parseDouble(Weather[3]) + ", Time: " 
          + Double.parseDouble(Weather[4]) + ", Total: " 
                     + Double.parseDouble(Weather[5]) + ", Overall: " 
                      + Double.parseDouble(Weather[6]) + "]");
          AVGDate = (Double.parseDouble(Weather[0]) / 804);
          System.out.println(AVGDate);
      }     

    System.out.println("What data is wanted?");
    analysisStr = console.readLine();
    analysis = Integer.parseInt(analysisStr);

    if(analysis == 0) {
        System.out.println("Date.");
        System.out.println("Minimum date is:");
        System.out.println("Maximum date is:");
        System.out.println("Average date is: " + AVGDate);
    }
    else if(analysis == 1) {
        System.out.println("Interval.");
        System.out.println("This data isn't useful.");
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

    System.out.println("Done.");

    }

   }
```

### Heading

The program above reads the file correctly, reads and prints out all the records but for my average date it is calculating each individual records date instead of calculating all the dates together, I am a novice user and really new to Java, I can't see what I am doing wrong. The other problem is that I don't know how to calculate the minimum/maximum data for each column. Just straight up not sure on how to do this.

Comment: What is average Date? Why do you divide by 804 ?

Comment: Why not sum all calculated values for `AVGDate` and divide it by the number of records?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate average you have to first calculate the total and divide it by number of elements. So initialize `total` and sum it up in while loop every time you read a data.

```
double total = 0.0

while(...) {
    ...
    total += Double.parseDouble(Weather[0]);
}
AVGDate = total / 804;
```

Now about calculating minimum or maximum...

```
double minDate = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double maxDate = Double.MIN_VALUE;
while(...) {
    // parse each data
    double temp = Weather[0];    
    if(temp < minDate) {
        minDate = temp;
    }

    else if(temp > maxDate) {
        maxDate = temp;
    }
}
```

also keep in mind we use [lower-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java) convention for non final variable naming.

Comment: Use a [CSVReader](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html) for clean code.

Comment: I get incorrect outputs using this, it seems that the system only reads the first record if I do this? Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=iTTBXPq1 , the outputs are Minimum date is: 1.7976931348623157E308
Maximum date is: 4.9E-324
Average date is: 1943.5796019900497

Comment: @user3135026 well when I wrote `while(...){ }` that doesn't mean you have to introduce a new `while` loop. I meant that include the code into the already exists `while` loop.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=QSRyMwhV , the average isn't working, it's dividing each date by the 804 individually and not adding them together? Thanks again

Comment: Initialize `total` before `while` loop and keep `total += Double.parseDouble(Weather[0]);` in `while` loop. Do the average after `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, got it working, you're a legend, hope you had a good christmas!