# add item to listview by edittext

Tags: java, android

i have edittext and button and list view, i want to add item to listview from edittext, when i click on button text from edittext add to listview but this error will appear "Unfortunately, List has stopped."

***> main.xml code is:***

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EdtInput"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/StInput"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/BtnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/StAdd"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EdtInput"
    />

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/LstItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EdtInput"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EdtInput"
    ></ListView>
```

***> MainActivity.java code is:***

package com.saly.list;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText ET=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdtInput);
    final String StInput=ET.getText().toString();
    final ListView LV=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.LstItem);
    final ArrayList<String> ArLi=new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,ArLi);
    LV.setAdapter(ArAd);
    Button Add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnAdd);
    Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArLi.add(StInput);
            ArAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ET.setText("");
        }       
    });     
}
}
```

**This is the LogCat error:**

```
02-27 16:44:06.369: I/Adreno-EGL(21719): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
02-27 16:44:06.409: D/OpenGLRenderer(21719): Enabling debug mode 0
02-27 16:44:12.515: E/ArrayAdapter(21719): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
02-27 16:44:12.515: D/AndroidRuntime(21719): Shutting down VM
02-27 16:44:12.515: W/dalvikvm(21719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41836ba8)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719): Process: com.saly.list, PID: 21719
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
02-27 16:44:12.525: E/AndroidRuntime(21719):    ... 40 more
```

Comment: On a side note, it's worth thinking about how you name your variables - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move  final String StInput=ET.getText().toString(); in your onClick method.

```
Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String StInput= ET.getText().toString();
        if(StInput != null && StInput.length() > 0){
            ArLi.add(StInput);
            ArAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ET.setText("");
        }else{
           //EditText is blank
        }
    }       
});
```

EDIT - Please add this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,ArLi);
```

I believe you are using a simple list of Strings. The issue is with your layout you are passing it as you have passed your main layout there. Change it to above and let know if this works.

Comment: tnx bro, but this "Unfortunately, List has stopped." error still appear.

Comment: I feel the issue now is something to do with the adapter. Can you post the error Log Cat as well?

Comment: 02-27 16:21:01.861: E/ArrayAdapter(20169): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Comment: ArrayAdapter acceps a TextView in its constructor. So please add a default one provide by android. See my edits. Or the one you have in your main layout.

Comment: Can you post your adapter and the error message too. Also are you calling super() in your ArrayAdapter constructor?

Comment: 02-27 16:30:31.519: E/AndroidRuntime(21018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-27 16:30:31.519: E/AndroidRuntime(21018): Process: com.saly.list, PID: 21018

02-27 16:30:31.519: E/AndroidRuntime(21018): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from xml type layout resource ID #0x1020014

02-27 16:30:31.519: E/AndroidRuntime(21018):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2356)

Comment: Please post it in your question by editing it, so that it is more clear and others can see it too. Also please post you ArrayAdapters code.

Comment: Do this instead of what I said earlier, ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,ArLi);

Comment: thank u so much Atul, i change "final ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,ArLi);" to "ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,ArLi);"
it's working, can u tell me where was problem and why?

Comment: Huh, finally it worked. :) As @Ben Pearson said, please consider following naming conventions. Had it been more clear and visible problem would have got spotted earlier. Anyways, the issue was with the layout you were passing to your ArrayAdapter (which was your main). If you have simple string then use default layout provide in android as the one I mentioned above and in case you have a custom layout then pass that. Please visit google docs for more detaisl on ArrayAdpater;s constructors and other options. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

I am saving the edittext value in DB and instantly showing it in list 
here is my code

```
    mEditProblem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       // calculate();
                        saveContentToDb();
                    }
                });

            mEditProblem.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {          

                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if(!hasFocus){
                           // calculate();
                            //if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditProblem.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                           // }
    //                      saveContentToDb();
                        }
                    }
                });


public void saveContentToDb(){

        newlyAddedText = mEditProblem.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mEditProblem.getText().toString(), 0).show();
        itemData.add(new ItemRow(mEditProblem.getText().toString(),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher) ));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mEditProblem.setText("");



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the text when the app first loads. It's never updated.
You need to get the text when the button event is raised.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText ET=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdtInput);
    final ListView LV=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.LstItem);
    final ArrayList<String> ArLi=new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,ArLi);
    LV.setAdapter(ArAd);
    Button Add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnAdd);
    Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArLi.add(ET.getText().toString());
            ArAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ET.setText("");
        }       
    });     
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` displays data stored in your `ArLi` variable. What you need to to is add the string as you did. That part works just fine.

Your problem is that you get the text from the `EditText` before the button is clicked. Hence clicking the button will always add nothing (or the default value of the `EditText`. To get the text in the box upon clicking the button you need to change your `OnClickListener` as follows:

```
Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = ET.getText().toString();
        if(input != null && input != "")
        {
            ArLi.add(ET.getText().toString());
            ArAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ET.setText("");
        }
    }       
});
```

Note that I presume you don't want to add `null` or an empty string. Adjust as needed. I would also strongly advise that you take a look at Java coding practices. Variables should start with a lower letter. Also, writing concrete variable names instead of abbreviations will help to make your code more readable.

Comment: tnx Eric, the error still appear
what do u mean change your OnClickListener ?

Comment: Well you never added anything. You got the text in the call to `create()` but never got another value. Hence the need to add the line for getting the text into the listener before you can actually add the text the user wrote. I see the accepted solution mentioned the reason for the error upon the missing Id. I hope it works for you now!