# How can I get Entity by name in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I have entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class CrmUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    ...
```

And I have DAO with `EntityManager` How can I get user by `username`?

```
@Override
    public User getUser(String login) throws Exception {
        User crmUser = (User) userJpaDao.getEntityManager()..............
        return crmUser;
    }
```

Comment: `"select user from CrmUser user where user.username = :username"`

Comment: How is it done in ANY JPA TUTORIAL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "USER")
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name="CrmUser.getManagerByUserName",
                query="Select o From CrmUser o Where lower(o.username) = lower(:prm_sUserName)"
            )

    })
    public class CrmUser implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String username;
```

> Function To Retrieve `User` according to your `username`.

```
 private CrmUser findByUserName(String prm_userName){
    TypedQuery<CrmUser > v_objQuery;
    CrmUser obj_UserFoundWithUserName;
    EntityManager g_objUserEntityManager;
    g_objUserEntityManager= ?????.getEntityManager(); //provide your dao Class to get your entity Manager.
    v_objQuery = g_objUserEntityManager.createNamedQuery(CrmUser .class.getSimpleName() + ".getUserByUserName", CrmUser.class);
    v_objQuery.setParameter("prm_sUserName", prm_userName);
    obj_UserFoundWithUserName= v_objQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: @Miles what did you mean..  I Have Just giving a solution as per i am implementing in my project actually..

Comment: @VikrantKashyap what Miles is pointing is you are not following the standards for the variables names. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java