# JSON with spaces in variable names

Tags: java, parsing, gson, android

I have a JSON with spaces in the variable names something like the following:

```
{
     "First Name":"John",
     "Last Name":"Smith"
}
```

Since Java doesn't allow spaces in variable names I'm trying to see if Gson has a provision to parse this into **First_Name** or **FirstName** or something of that sort so I can use **First_Name** or **FirstName** as the variable name in my Java class to represent this data.

Is there a way to do it or will I need to make a local copy of the JSON and run a String parser through the JSON file to rename the variables and then pass it on to Gson to do the rest?

Any ideas?

Note: This JSON is being sent by a third-party API I am using, not my own creation. So while I wish I could tell them about proper naming conventions, that isn't where I would like to spend my time :)

Comment: How do you plan to use a JSON key/label to create a Java class?

Comment: My first thought: use `label.replaceAll("[_ ]", "")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have  you tried  using field naming support. My first guess is it sshould work with spaces in the name (https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support). Something like below should work.

Tried the below , it works (I don't agree with the naming , but it works)

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class SOMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = "{\"First Name\":\"John\",\"Last Name\":\"Smith\"}";

        Employee employee = gson.fromJson(json, Employee.class);

        System.out.println(employee);

    }

}


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Employee {

    @SerializedName("Last Name")
    public String lastName;
    @SerializedName("First Name")
    public String firstName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Employee with first name " + firstName + " and last name " + lastName ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ramachandran that worked! Using the SerializedName annotation worked. I was hung up on trying to create a custom FieldNamingSupport but that is required only for the reverse process, of creating a JSON out of Java object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, name your variable `firstName` in your java code, see [Variable naming conventions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java)

Second, to change field names with Gson: here is a great tutorial: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/