# How to easily insert mp3/mp4 file metadata into a TableView using javafx? (the Tableview has been built using Scenebuilder)

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a mediaplayer and need to insert mp3 file metadata into a TableView.

I need help for retrieving the data from a folder of files, and then inserting said data into the TableView. the data to be retrieved is the Title, Album and Artist.

I would need a simple option if possible. Important: the TableView has already been created in the Scenebuilder so it would help it the code was connected to the FXML part.

the Main function

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {


//launching from main page
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main window.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("WaterPlayer");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

the Controller

```
 package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Modality;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;




    public class Controller implements Initializable {

    //button actions
    @FXML
    public void AddButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("add window.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void MusicButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("music window.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void MovieButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("movie window.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void PlaylistButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("playlist window.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();

    }


    @FXML
    public void BackButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main window.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void RandomButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle("");
        window.setMinWidth(100);
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("RANDOM:");
        Button musicButton = new Button("Music");
        Button movieButton = new Button("Movie");
        movieButton.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
        musicButton.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, musicButton, movieButton);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    public void SearchBar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("search window.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void CreateButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("name playlist.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void Playlistname(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent Main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("playlist window.fxml"));
        Scene Main_scene = new Scene(Main_parent);
        Stage Main_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        Main_stage.setScene(Main_scene);
        Main_stage.show();
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

the FXML file

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="650.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.101" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <bottom>
      <Button fx:id="Back" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#BackButtonClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Back" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="12.5" left="555.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </Button>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ChoiceBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" top="12.5" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </ChoiceBox>
            <TextField fx:id="SearchBar" onAction="#SearchBar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="185.0" promptText="Search...">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="295.0" top="12.5" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </TextField>
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </HBox>
   </top>
    <center>
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="196.0" prefWidth="197.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="630.0">
           <children>
              <TableView fx:id="Musiclist" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="615.0">
                <columns>

                  <TableColumn fx:id="Title" prefWidth="219.0" text="Title">

                  </TableColumn>

                  <TableColumn fx:id="Album" prefWidth="200.0" text="Album">

                  </TableColumn>

                    <TableColumn fx:id="Author" prefWidth="219.0" text="Author">

                    </TableColumn>
                </columns>
              </TableView>

           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </content>
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="12.5" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
     </BorderPane.margin>
  </ScrollPane>
```

and the Song Class

```
    package sample;
public class Song {
    private String Title;


    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {

        return Album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        Album = album;
    }

    private String Album;

    public String getAuthor() {
        return Author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        Author = author;
    }

    private String Author;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How do I retrieve ID3 metadata from mp3s:** Use a java library to extract the metadata like [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) or [jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). jaudiotagger for example uses the following syntax:

```
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(testFile);
Tag tag = f.getTag();
AudioHeader = f.getAudioHeader();

tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.COMMENT);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.YEAR);
```

**How to insert data into the tableview:**

```
ObservableList<Song> songs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//populate your observable list here
Musiclist.setItems(songs);
```

Adjust this snipet and add them to your fxml, so that the tableview knows which data from your Song-class it has to display.

```
<TableColumn fx:id="Title" prefWidth="219.0" text="Title">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="Title" />
    </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

Comment: how do i populate the observable list? because everytime i type ".setItems" it tells me "cannot resolve symbol 'setItems'

Comment: Please show me the whole code and the whole error. Otherwise it is hard to tell what the problem is.

BTW you should start the names your objects (Musiclist, Title, etc.) with a lowercase letter. Otherwise they will be mistaken for classes (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java)).

Comment: ObservableList<Song> songs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Musiclist.setItems(songs);                                                                              i type this in my controller and it tells me "cannot resolve symbol 'setItems' " thats all that happens

Comment: I have no problem running this code `ObservableList<Song> songs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); TableView<Song> Musiclist = new TableView<>(); Musiclist.setItems(songs);`.

Comment: i keep on trying but nothing works , i still get the same error, maybe its due to where i put this code in my program, where did you put it?

Comment: Please update your code then and also show the full error you are getting.