# Search the records without a primary key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Entity class as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Calendar_Month")
public class Calendar_Month {
    @Id
    @Transient
    private int Calendar_Month_ID;
    private String Calendar_Year;
    private String Calendar_Month;
    private String Calendar_Country;
```

with corresponding getters and setters.

I have written a Spring data jpa repository for this table access as below.

```
@Resource
public interface CalendarMonthRepository extends CrudRepository<Calendar_Month, Long> {

}
```

But i want to read all the records using  `Calendar_Month` value. But `Calendar_Month` is not a primary key. So i was wondering how to achieve this.

Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to supply some Calendar_Month instance and find all records with corresponding values? Or just get all database entries of that type?

Comment: I want to get a result for the query `Select * from Calendar_Month where Calendar_Month="May" `

Comment: List<CalendarMonth> findByCalendar_Month(String calendar_month); should work AFAIK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) 
like this

```
@Repository
public interface CalendarMonthRepository extends CrudRepository<Calendar_Month, Long> {
   List<Calendar_Month> findByCalendar_Month(String calendar_Month)
}
```

You can find what kind of queries can be created this way from Spring Data [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: Indeed. The CrudRepository interface only defines methods for handling entities via their instances and primary keys. You'll need to make use of other Spring facilities or the JPA JPQL/Criteria queries to perform more complex queries.

Comment: But i was wondering how spring will find how should be the implementation of `List<User> findByCalendar_Month(String calendar_Month)`? How it will decide whether this method should search records, or update records etc..

Comment: spring-data uses name of the method to create code for the interface. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1):

You have marked Calendar_Month_ID with @Id. Annotation @Id "Specifies the primary key of an entity.". Either make Calendar_Month_ID primary key, or move @Id annotation to real primary key of this entity. In your CalendarMonthRepository, you should be able to create method like:

```
public CalendarMonth findByCalendarMonthId(Long calendarMonthId)
```

Creation of CrudRepository methods: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

P.S. Check java variableNamingConvention: [Variable naming conventions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java)