# On calling getcellData() getting no values from excel - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, apache-poi

Here is my excel utils class:

```
package utility;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
public class ExcelUtils {
    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    private static XSSFCell cell;
    private static XSSFRow row;
    //This method is to set the File path and to open the Excel 
    file, Pass Excel Path and Sheetname as Arguments to this method
    public static void setExcelFile(String Path, String SheetName) throws Exception {
        try {
            // Open the Excel file
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
            // Access the required test data sheet
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
    //This method is to read the test data from the Excel cell, in this we are passing parameters as Row num and Col num
    public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {
        try {
            String cellData = "";
            cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
            cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
            return cellData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "undefined";
        }
    }
    //This method is to write in the Excel cell, Row num and Col num are the parameters
    public static void setCellData(String Result, int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {
        try {
            row = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
            cell = row.getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(ColNum);
                cell.setCellValue(Result);
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(Result);
            }
            // Constant variables Test Data path and Test Data file name
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Constants.Path_TestData + Constants.File_TestData);
            ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the script where I'm calling the getCellData to get the values from Excel:

```
String cellData = ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 1);
System.out.println("CellData :" + cellData);
```

Here is the excel file format:

```
TestCaseName | Username | Password 
TC_01        | TestData |
```

Output:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(ExcelUtils.java:63)
    at testScripts.Category_creation.main(Category_creation.java:47)
```

Here is the [excel](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ad5f9a16f7fba14cb13cd3f7c71c6f2d20180821161550/66610d9c4c816a62cc2f4e85bf32666f20180821161550/83a22e?utm_campaign=WT_email_tracking&utm_content=general&utm_medium=download_button&utm_source=notify_recipient_email) I'am using. Not able to fetch data from excel file. I'm using Page object framework, hence the excel utils file contains only the code and in fetching the data in testScript by passing row and column number.

Comment: Removed [selenium] since this question has nothing to do with Selenium. You should add a tag for whatever library you are using to access Excel.

Answer (score 1):

**POI 3.9**

please add `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);` after `cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);`

i.e.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
...
                             try{

                            cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
                            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                            String CellData = cell.getStringCellValue();

                            return CellData;

                            }catch (Exception e){

                                return"";

                            }
```

or you can use this construct

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;

                    default:
```

source http://www.java67.com/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html

and please rename the variable  `private static XSSFCell Cell;` to `cell`. ([Variable naming conventions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java))

**UPDATE 1**

**POI 3.17** you could also uncomment `switch-case` block, it works for POI 3.17

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Excel {

    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;

    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;

    private static XSSFCell xCell;

    private static XSSFRow xRow;  

    public static void main(String... args) {

     try {
        InputStream is = readInputStreamFromFile();

        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
        ExcelWSheet = mySheet;

        System.out.println(getCellData(1, 0));
        System.out.println(getCellData(1, 1));

        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }


    public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception{

          try {

            String cellData = "";

            xCell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            xCell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
            cellData = xCell.getStringCellValue();

//            switch (xCell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
//            case STRING:
//                //System.out.print(xCell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
//                cellData = xCell.getStringCellValue();
//                break;
//            case NUMERIC:
//              cellData = String.valueOf(xCell.getNumericCellValue());
//                //System.out.print(xCell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
//                break;
//            case BOOLEAN:
//              cellData = String.valueOf(xCell.getBooleanCellValue());
//                //System.out.print(xCell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
//                break;
//
//            default:
//              cellData = "undefined";
//            }

            return cellData;

            } catch (Exception e){

                return "undefined";

            }
    }

    private static InputStream readInputStreamFromFile() throws Exception {
        try {

            File f = new File("C:\\path to your file\\TestData.xlsx");

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
            try {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you might need `cell.getCellTypeEnum()` - depending in the poi version you are using

Comment: @Kaustubh, please add your excel file. I've tested with apache-poi version 3.9 and it works fine. What poi version you are using?

Comment: @John: I have attached the excel file I'am using. poi version is 3.17

Comment: @Kaustubh, I've updated my answer, please see `UPDATE 1`

Comment: @John: Thanks. But in getting the print result of getcellData as undefined. I have updated my entire code for excel utils. Please have a look.

Comment: @Kaustubh, "undefined" is returned when an exception occurs. Could you provide the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @John: updated the question with the output. Please have a look.

Comment: @Kaustubh, I can't see the 63s line of your code where the exception occurs. Could you add the method with line's numeration where exception occurs? Also please debug your project and you will see what is the cause of the execption. I've added void main with `setExcelFile("C:\\path\\to\\file\\TestData.xlsx", "Sheet1");
     System.out.println(getCellData(1, 1));` and it works fine.